# The delete button is duplicating when you create a second task so that you see two delete buttons for the second task

Tags: javascript, html

I have a to do list that is creating two delete buttons per task for the second task item, three delete buttons for the third task etc. Here is my code.

```js
//Submits the form
function submitForm() {
  form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    taskData = document.getElementById('activity').value;
    addingTask(taskData);
    form.reset(taskData);

    return taskData;
  });
}

//Adds a task element
function addingTask(taskData) {
  taskElement = document.createElement('h3');
  deleteButton = document.createElement('Button');
  taskElement.innerHTML = taskData;
  taskElement.id = 'taskElement';
  deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete';
  //deleteButton.id = taskData;
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', deletingTask);
  document.body.appendChild(taskElement);
  document.body.appendChild(deleteButton);
}

//Removes a task element
function deletingTask() {
  taskElement.remove();
  deleteButton.remove();
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form id="form"> <label for="activity">Activity</label><br> <input type="text" id="activity"
            name="activity"><br><br> <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()"> </form>
    <!-- your content here... -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: No that's not what happens. You set it up so that every time you submit the form, you add another submit listener. So the second time, two listeners run, the third time three run, etc. And since you reset the form contents inside of the listener, the second/third/etc. time the listener runs, the field was already reset, so it adds an empty h3 element plus delete button.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create new event listeners each time you submit the form. Add the event listener only once:

```js
//Submits the form
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  taskData = document.getElementById('activity').value;
  addingTask(taskData);
  form.reset(taskData);

  return taskData;
});

//Adds a task element
function addingTask(taskData) {
  taskElement = document.createElement('h3');
  deleteButton = document.createElement('Button');
  taskElement.innerHTML = taskData;
  taskElement.id = 'taskElement';
  deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete';
  //deleteButton.id = taskData;
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', deletingTask);
  document.body.appendChild(taskElement);
  document.body.appendChild(deleteButton);
}

//Removes a task element
function deletingTask() {
  taskElement.remove();
  deleteButton.remove();
}
```

```html
<form id="form"> 

  <label for="activity">Activity</label><br> <input type="text" id="activity" name="activity">

  <br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you  do this each time you submit

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
```

Also form.reset does not take a parameter.
Lastly ne need to return the data in the submit event

You should delegate and have a div per task

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
//Submits the form
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  taskData = document.getElementById('activity').value;
  addingTask(taskData);
  this.reset();
});

container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("delete")) {
    //Removes a task element
    tgt.closest("div").remove();
  }
})


//Adds a task element
function addingTask(taskData) {
  const taskElement = document.createElement('div');
  const header = document.createElement('h3');
  deleteButton = document.createElement('Button');
  header.innerHTML = taskData;
  deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete';
  deleteButton.classList.add("delete");
  taskElement.appendChild(header);
  taskElement.appendChild(deleteButton);
  container.append(taskElement);
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="activity">Activity</label>
  <input type="text" id="activity" name="activity">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <div id="container"></div>
</form>
```